# Describe property object in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, webstorm, typescript2.0

I want to describe some interface with nested objects. How can I do it without creation of Interfaces for nested objects?

```
interface ISome {
  strProp:string;
  complexProp:{
    someStrKeyWhichIsDynamic:{
      value:string;
      optValue?:string;
    }
  };
}
```

I also tried (**UPD: it's okay actually**)

```
interface ISome {
  strProp:string;
  complexProp:{
    [someStrKeyWhichIsDynamic:string]:{
      value:string;
      optValue?:string;
    }
  };
}
```

But I cant to assign an object like

```
let dynamicStrKey = 'myKey';
  {
   strProp:'str', 
   complexProp:{
     [dynamicStrKey]:{
       value:'something here',
       optValue: 'ok, that too',
    }
  };
```

to variable with `ISome` type without type assertion `<ISome>`. At least WebStorm highlights this assignment as an error.

How to properly describe nested objects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally, I think that my second variant was correct

```
interface ISome {
  strProp:string;
  complexProp:{
    [someStrKeyWhichIsDynamic:string]:{
      value:string;
      optValue?:string;
    }
  };
}
```

For dynamic key you can just write `[dynamic:string]` to specify that here will be some string property. Seems like I had webstorm error which wasn't related to the issue.

BTW, if you have some string based enum, you may want to use `[key in MyEnum]: {...}` instead of `[key:string]`. That solves error:

> TS1337 an index signature parameter type can not be a union type.

And if you have a literal object, e.g. 
`const obj = { prop1: 'blah', prop2: 'blahblah' }`

You may want to use `[key in keyof typeof obj]: {...}` to describe that your dynamic key can be only 'prop1' or 'prop2' (or, more generic, value from `Object.keys(obj`) )

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your first two examples. They both compile fine, and mean what they say.

In your third example, you apparently want the property name to be "dynamic". But remember, TS operates at compile time. At compile time, `dynamicStrKey` has no value yet. Therefore, it is meaningless to try to use it as a property name in a type definition. You cannot define a compile-time artifact using a run-time value.

Comment: But if I want to have dynamic property, how I should describe it? I want to specify that here will be some property, it should be a string and it should have some object value, which described too.

Comment: As I said, if I understand your question correctly, you cannot define a compile-time TS type with a property whose value is not known until run-time.

Answer (score 2):

the code of the second part is support dynamic properties.you can't use with the last one,because type not emit to the javascript code.I think you just like something below,using generic instead.for more details,you can see typescript [index types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

```
interface ISome<K extends string> {
    strProp: string;
    complexProp: {
        [P in K]: {
            value: string;
            optValue?: string;
        }
    };
}


let foo: ISome<"foo"> = {
    strProp:"foo",
    complexProp:{
        foo:{
            value:"foo"
        }
    }
};

let bar: ISome<"bar"> = {
    strProp:"bar",
    complexProp:{
        bar:{
            value:"bar",
            optValue:"<optional>"
        }
    }
};

let foobar: ISome<"foo"|"bar"> = {
    strProp:"foo",
    complexProp:{
        foo:{
            value:"foo"
        },
        bar:{
            value:"bar",
            optValue:"<optional>"
        }
    }
};

// interesting things that use with any|never types
let anything:ISome<any|never>={
    strProp:"foo",
    complexProp:{}
};
```